# Python exchangelib read mails in subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x, exchangelib

I want to read the mails from the subfolder of the outlook mailbox.

```
Inbox
├──myfolder
```

I can read Inbox using `account.inbox.all()` but i want to read mails in `myfolder`

I tried the things in `folder` section of this page but i couldn't get it right

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/exchangelib/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get hold of the `Folder` instance for `myfolder` first:

```
my_folder = account.inbox / 'myfolder'
for i in my_folder.all():
    print(i.subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you have **a lot of sub-folders (including nested ones)** inside your directory and you want to print the subject of all then use this method.

```
folder = account.root/'Top of Information Store'/'Inbox'/folder_name
all_folders = folder.glob('**/*')
for subfolders in all_folders:
    for emails in subfolders.all():
        print(emails.subject)
```